# Can javascript run through browser as some plugin

Tags: javascript, browser, plugins

I am very confused on this one but can javascript run through browser without pasting it into console?

The meaning of this is that I like watching movies online but websites that let us see movies for free are showing lot of ads some of them cant be blocked by adblockers etc so I open developer tools and find elements that are used for ads and by javascript remove them.

And I may be using 30 sites and I made one code for each and one big code for all but my question is can I make some web browser plugin that will when being active at the time when I open some website, run code and if the site is in my code find for ads and remove it?

The main idea is that can I make plugin that will do all job for me instead me doing it every time I want to watch something?

Comment: Can make a  `userscript` that runs in browser extensions like Tampermonkey or Greasemonkey and will run on domains you define

Comment: @charlietfl Since I was just thinking about that, I'll need to research for that first and thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Most browsers support extensions. Take a look at chrome extensions development https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts. It allows to run `content scripts` for a specific websites. This is primarily a chrome API but Firefox and Mircosoft Edge also partially support it. And they definitely support `content scripts` API

Comment: Thank you too I will check it all!